# Generating two random numbers and subtracting them

Tags: python

I need to do this, and I have come up with this for adding:

```
import random
mynos = []

print ("First, we'll do some addition")

for counter in range (0,2):
      mynumber = random.randint(1,20)
      mynos.append(mynumber)
print(mynos)

the_answer = sum(mynos)
#print(the_answer) (^^^)

player_answer =int(input("What is the answer?"))

def main():
      if player_answer is the_answer:
            print ("Correct! Well done!")
            print ("You scored 1 out of 10 so far!")
            print ("Good job!")
      else:
            print ("Incorrect! You scored null points!")
            print ("You have zero out of 10 so far!")
            exit()

main()
```

That was the adding part of the program, but instead of using `sum` is there anything to use for subtracting the two randomly generated numbers in `mynos`?

Comment: The problem here is that with `sum` the order of the elements do not matter. With subtraction, the ordering of the elements **will**  affect the result. Perhaps a manual subtraction command is the right way to go here.

Comment: `import operator; reduce(operator.sub, mynos)`

Is it only ever two numbers? Why not use distinct variables then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only ever have 2 integers, just use subtraction on the individual elements:

```
the_answer = mynos[0] - mynos[1]
```

The 'functional' way to subtract numbers in a sequence is to use the [`reduce()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
import operator
try:
    # Python 3 moved reduce to the functools module
    from functools import reduce
except ImportError:
    pass

the_answer = reduce(operator.sub, mynos)
```

The [`operator.sub()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.sub) stands in for the `-` operator in that case.

Comment: May be add abs(n) to the result. If it does not want to show negative result and just the difference between two.

Comment: @planet260: I think I know what exercise the OP is trying to complete; there are a few dozen related questions going round at the moment. They don't care about absolute results. Next up: multiplication and division.

Comment: @planet260 - true - but `difference` is not the same as `subtraction`. This might be the case, but it needs to be verified with the OP.

Comment: Thanks for your help.. my program works just fine now!